Deserialize mixed objects in JSON array using Kotlin Serialization
The following JSON is an array of a string and an array of an object (that has a key and a value). Given these heterogeneous item types in an array, how do I de-serialize it using Kotlin Serialization?
[
    "text",
    [
        {
            "key":"value"
        }
    ]
]

It would be easy if all items are of the same type (i.e. either all strings or objects of the same kind), but I have no control over the format.

[One possible solution]
After going back and forth with different options, I decided to transform the given JSON to something that is easier to work with. In this particular case, the first item in the list (i.e. string) is going to be tag, and the next item in the list (i.e. list) is going to be data.
@Serializable
data class ListItem(
    val tag: String,
    val data: List<Data>,
)

@Serializable
data class Data(
    val key: String,
)

Once the data structure is ready, we can go through the JSON elements and re-arrange them according to the structure.
object ListItemSerializer : JsonTransformingSerializer<List<ListItem>>(
    ListSerializer(ListItem.serializer())
) {
    override fun transformDeserialize(element: JsonElement): JsonElement {
        return buildJsonArray {
            addJsonObject {
                // Note: Shouldn't make assumptions in real life.
                put("tag", element.jsonArray[0])
                put("data", element.jsonArray[1])
            }
        }
    }
}

And then verify the result.
val string = """
    [
        "text",
        [
            {
                "key":"value"
            }
        ]
    ]
    """.trimMargin()

val listFromString = Json.decodeFromString(ListItemSerializer, string)
val list = listOf(
    ListItem(
        tag = "text",
        data = listOf(
            Data(key = "value")
        )
    )
)
assertEquals(list, listFromString)


Did you try online code generators? There are some tools that generate POJO classes for you. Try https://json2kt.com/ for example.

Tried a few but none worked well enough to use. For example, "var 0 : String? = null" isn't even a valid Kotlin statement.

Try this.
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.*

@Serializable(with = ItemSerializer::class)
sealed class Item

@Serializable
data class StringItem(val value: String) : Item()

@Serializable
data class ObjectItem(val key: String, val value: String) : Item()

object ItemSerializer : JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer<Item>(Item::class) {
    override fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement): DeserializationStrategy<out Item> {
        return when {
            element is JsonPrimitive && element.isString -> StringItem.serializer()
            element is JsonObject && element.keys.contains("key") -> ObjectItem.serializer()
            else -> throw SerializationException("Unknown item type")
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    val json = """
        [
            "text",
            [
                {
                    "key":"value"
                }
            ]
        ]
    """.trimIndent()

    val items = Json.decodeFromString<List<Item>>(json)
    items.forEach {
        when (it) {
            is StringItem -> println("String: ${it.value}")
            is ObjectItem -> println("Object: ${it.key} -> ${it.value}")
        }
    }
}


I'm getting "kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected class kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonObject as the serialized body of StringItem, but had class kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonLiteral", possibly because "text" (i.e. the first item in array) is a literal string, not an object. Any suggestions on how to handle such a case?
